# Views and Taxonomy Filtering

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a question regarding filtering in Views.

**My setup:**

• I have a content-type, for example: Cars
• I have a few different taxonomy term fields attached to that node, something like: Car brand, Car color, Car type, with the following terms:

- Vocabulary: Car brand

  - Term:Car Brand A
  - Term: Car Brand B
  - Term:Car Brand C
- Vocabulary: Car color

  - Term: Blue
  - Term: Red
  - Term: Black
- Vocabulary: Car type

  - Term: Two seater
  - Term: SUV
  - Term: Sedan

I have a View that displays all the available cars, and I used Better Exposed Filters to display a block that displays those taxonomy fields as filters. Now: this is were I get stuck.

Say for example, that 'Car Brand A' only only sells Blue and Black Sedans. What I would like is that the color option 'red' and car types 'SUV' and 'Two seater' are hidden as selectable option, and re-added if a user selects other brands. How do I do that?

I really hope you can help me with this! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the functionality of the [Views Selective Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) module.

Although I haven't used this module myself, I've written a similar Views handler in a custom module. This filter handler removes all options from select lists that don't provide any results (due to other selected values). If the [Views Selective Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) doesn't provide the desired functionality, I can create a sandbox project of my code.

Comment: Wooh!!! This module sound nice.. :)

Comment: Views Selective Filter did the trick. Documentation is not so good, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, good to hear your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

View's default expose filter didn't give such functionality. You may need the [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) module.

I have seen it in Commerce Kickstart package but didn't use it from fresh setup.